# Ayuda Netbeans java error en ciclo for

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, en mi universidad abrí el mismo proyecto y funciono correctamente, pero en mi casa suelta este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

JSP:

```xhtml
<%@page import="controlador.AccesoDatos"%>

<%@page import="modelo.*"%>

<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>



<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>LISTADO DE LIBROS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% 
        AccesoDatos a = new AccesoDatos();
        %>
        <h1 align="center">Libros Almacenados</h1>

        <table align="center"   border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>CODIGO</th>
                <th>AUTOR</th>
                <th>NOMBRE</th>
                <th>ESTADO</th>
            </tr>
            <%
            ArrayList<Libro> listL = new ArrayList();
            listL = a.listarLibros();
            for(Libro lib : listL){
                out.println("<tr>");
                   out.println("<td>"+lib.getCodigo()+"</td>");
                   out.println("<td>"+lib.getAutor()+"</td>");
                   out.println("<td>"+lib.getNombre()+"</td>");
                   out.println("<td>"+lib.getEstado()+"</td>");
                out.println("</tr>");
            }
            %>
        </table>



    </body>
</html>
```

El código de `AccesoDatos`:

```
public class AccesoDatos {
private  ResultSet rs = null;
private Connection con = null;
private Statement sentencia = null;

private ArrayList<Comuna> listC;
private ArrayList<Libro> listL;
private ArrayList<Pelicula> listP;
private ArrayList<Vendedor> listV;

private Comuna com;
private Libro lib;
private Pelicula peli;
private Vendedor vend;


private void conectar (){
    try{
        String parametros = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/libros?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(parametros,"root","");

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.print("No se ha podido conectar");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("No se ha podido conectar");
    }
}

private void desconectar (){
    try{
       con.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.print("No se ha podido desconectar");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("No se ha podido desconectar");
    }
}

public ArrayList<Libro> listarLibros(){
    try{
        conectar();
        sentencia = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from libro";
        sentencia.executeQuery(sql);
        listL = new ArrayList();
        while(rs.next()){
            int codigoL = rs.getInt("cod_lib");
            String autorL = rs.getString("aut_lib");
            String nombreL = rs.getString("nom_lib");
            String estadiL = rs.getString("est_lib");
        lib = new Libro(codigoL,autorL,nombreL,estadiL);    
        listL.add(lib);
        }
        sentencia.close();
        desconectar();
        return listL;

    }catch(SQLException e){
        return null;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu código de respuesta y el que pusiste en tu pregunta es exactamente igual la única diferencia es esta linea `rs = sentencia.executeQuery(sql);` en tu pregunta no tienes asignada una respuesta a `rs` por eso marca error

Answer (score 3):

Parece que está entrando al catch de listarLibros prueba agregando estas lineas a listarLibros de AccesoDatos.

```
catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);
    return null;
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);
    return null;
}
```

y revisa los mensajes que te aparece en consola, el problema puede estar relacionado cuando se conecta con la base.
Saludos

Comment: Ya lo hice, y no suelta ningún error en la consola

Comment: @MickFoley me parece que lo que dice beta3000 es cierto. Deberías arreglar tu manejo de errores al conectarte a la base de datos. Solo estás imprimiendo un mensaje que dice "error", por lo menos deberías imprimir el stacktrace para ver en detalle qué sucedió. Revisa la salida que está en la consola/log de tu aplicación donde puedes ver ese detalle. Asimismo, no deberías retornar `null` sino una lista vacía para evitar estos problemas.

Comment: Mi profesor nos dice que pusieramos null, en la carpeta de logs de apache no me aparece nada :(, y en la de netbeans nisiquiera tengo una carpeta que se llame log

Comment: Olvida lo que te dijo el profesor. Retornar null **no significa absolutamente nada**. Haz un `e.printStackTrace()` para ver el origen del problema; de lo contrario, estás a ciegas.

Answer (score -1):

Logre encontrar la solucion, hice el javaclass AccesoDatos denuevo desde 0 y el error desaparecio.
Gracias por la ayuda, me qedo de esta manera.

```
public class AccesoDatos {
private  ResultSet rs = null;
private Connection con = null;
private Statement sentencia = null;

private ArrayList<Comuna> listC;
private ArrayList<Libro> listL;
private ArrayList<Pelicula> listP;
private ArrayList<Vendedor> listV;

private Comuna com;
private Libro lib;
private Pelicula peli;
private Vendedor vend;


private void conectar (){
    try{
        String parametros = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/libros?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(parametros,"root","");

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("ERROR DE CONEXION A LA BD");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("ERROR DE CONEXION ");
    }
}

private void desconectar (){
    try{
       con.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("ERROR DE CONEXION A LA BD");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("ERROR DE CONEXION ");
    }
}


public ArrayList<Libro> listarLibro(){
    try{
        conectar();
        String sql = "select * from libro";
        sentencia = con.createStatement();
        rs = sentencia.executeQuery(sql);
        listL = new ArrayList();
        while(rs.next()){
       int codigoL = rs.getInt("cod_lib");
            String autorL = rs.getString("aut_lib");
            String nombreL = rs.getString("nom_lib");
            String estadiL = rs.getString("est_lib");

            lib = new Libro(codigoL,autorL,nombreL,estadiL);
            listL.add(lib);

        }
        sentencia.close();
        desconectar();
        return listL;
    }catch(SQLException e){
        return null;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Genial, creo que puedes actualizar tu pregunta diciendo que encontraste la solucion en vez de publicarlo como otra respuesta :3